# Setting the default SocketFactory

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, ssl, cxf

I recently migrated my web services from Axis to CXF (2.1).  It appears that while Axis needed the "axis.socketSecureFactory" set, CXF grabs the default.  How do I set the default SocketFactory in Java to my own implementation (such as a property)?

What I am **not** looking to do is to set the default SocketFactory properties like setting the property for my truststore, keystore and passwords.

Comment: There is a pretty cool solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11696077

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the OpenJDK7 source code for [`javax.net.SocketFactory`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.java.html), the Sun JVM is hard coded to return a [`javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/javax/net/DefaultSocketFactory.html) for `getDefault();`

Edit:  However, the default SSLSocketFactory can be set by the security property `ssl.SocketFactory.provider`

Comment: In the code you can see that only returns that if you don't set another.

Comment: @ssedano The property's inaccessible from anywhere else, and the code defines a standard lazy instantiating getter. Powerlord is correct that the value is therefore effectively hard-coded.

Answer (score 7):

If we are talking about the standard sockets then `Socket.setSocketImplFactory(SocketImplFactory)` is used to change factory for ordinary sockets and `ServerSocket.setSocketFactory(SocketImplFactory)` for server sockets.

If you are using these, then take note of the fact that you can only set these factories once.

Note the java socket implementation defaults to using SocksSocketImpl (a package visible class in java.net) if the it discovers that the factory is `null` in case you want a factory that can switch pack to the standard java implementation.