# Hooking Java sockets to monitor socket in library code I can't modify

Tags: java, sockets

I'm using a Java library that uses a socket to communicate with the world.  I'd like to get a reference to that socket so I can monitor the data the library is sending and receiving.  Is there any way to hook Java's sockets system so I can monitor socket communications when I can't modify the code that creates the socket?

Comment: Would [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) statisfy your requirements? It's a program which can be used it to monitor any network connections on your system. Or do you want to write an own program which does that?

Comment: Thanks but no it won't satisfy. I need a tool within java - not an external application. I might have confused you when I wrote here "third party java application". Now I corrected to "Third party java library".

Comment: Close voters: this question is not a library recommendation; it's about hooking Java's sockets to monitor a library the asker is already using.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyBosboom for editing and clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at that idea:

[Finding out what network sockets are open in the current Java VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669554/finding-out-what-network-sockets-are-open-in-the-current-java-vm)

I haven't tested it, but it looks interesting as it presents a way to hook into the socket creation process of Java.

Comment: Thanks @udo. That question is similar but not identical to this. However, it is an excellent question with excellent self answer. One other answer there was also very useful: It referred to a thorough discussion about this issue in http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue169.html.All those readings armed me enough knowledge to solve this problem. Much thanks.