# Reuse a connected socket (java)

Tags: java, sockets

Struggling with what is probably simple syntax to 'retrieve' a reference to a socket which is already connected so I can 'reuse' it.

This code works fine (the socket stays open once created)-

```
String thisIP = var4.getString("ipaddress"); 

try {
    if ((this.socket == null || !this.socket.isConnected()) && this.running == 0) {
        this.running = 1;         
        socket = new Socket(thisIP, 2001);
    }
```

In a separate java class / file I need to 'retrieve' and reuse the socket, so something like -

queryStatus of the socket connected to "192.168.150.210" and return the entire socket reference (IP address, port number and locally bound IP port) so I can reuse it in a PrintWriter statement

```
new PrintWriter(s.getOutoutStream())
```

where s is the socket reference

I assume I require some sort of array to store all the previously created socket references?

I cant just create a new socket and use that because the third party IP device (a LAN module) only allows 1 TCP client connection.

Thoughts appreciated.
Regards
Ralph

Comment: Hmm, your question seems a bit unclear. "Reuse" in terms of socket usually means using it for **another** connection after it has been used. You seem to want to *retrieve* the reference to the socket somewhere else in the code, right?

Comment: Yes, retrieve the socket reference in another class (I know the IP address and have to retrieve the socket to that IP address so I can send data to it).

Comment: @Ralph Then your solution is a getter for socket.

Comment: Thanks, please elaborate, socket.getIP(ipaddress) or similar doesn't seem to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding out what network sockets are open in the current Java VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669554/finding-out-what-network-sockets-are-open-in-the-current-java-vm)

Comment: Additionally to the referenced duplicate question, your specific problem seems to boil down to "how do I store a reference in Java and access it later on?". That's a pretty basic, socket-unspecific problem.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to store a reference and the 'duplicate' suggestion is of no use because that can only run once (I have to run multiple times). I was rather hoping there would be a socket method that allowed me to retrieve the complete socket, obviously not.

Comment: Yeah, but exactly that information (there is no such method) is also given in the duplicate, so that flag may very well be valid...